# Help with Javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to add a java script slide show to my wordpress home page. In my theme folder I have a js folder and then in that I have jquery.cross-slide.min.js and jquery.min.js

This is what I have and what I'm pasting into my post area

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cross-slide.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function() {
crossSlide({
sleep: 3,
fade: 1
}, [
{ src: 'images/slideshows/block1.jpg' },
{ src: 'images/slideshows/block2.jpg' },
{ src: 'images/slideshows/block3.jpg' }
])
});
</script>
```

If I paste this into a wordpress page throught the html editor it doesn't work. Please could you check for errors and advice.

Comment: Fyi, there is also a Wordpress StackExchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - might be worth looking into for future Wordpress questions

Answer (score 0):

See the Wordpress Codex: [JavaScript in Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript).

> For the occasional or one time use of
>   Javascript, you need to put the script
>   into a Javascript file and then call
>   it out from within the post. Make sure
>   that each script is defined by its
>   function name such as:

```
function updatepage(){var m="Page updated "+document.lastMo.......}
```

> To include a Javascript inside a post,
>   you need to combine both the call to
>   the script file with the call to the
>   Javascript itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/updatepage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
updatepage();
//--></script>
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Please could you convert what I have so it will work like described by codex

Comment: @Michael Have you tried placing your scripts within the `/root/js` where `/root` is the main directory for the website?

Comment: @Michael Yes, add the HTML comments: `<!-- -->`